# core-default.xml location in hadoop-2.7.3

Tags: hadoop

I search all the file under hadoop-2.7.3 , but only find the `core-site.xml`.
Can I find the **core-default.xml** under the Hadoop installation directories?

Whether I can only found it in  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/core-default.html?

Answer (score 0):

It will be in `hadoop-2.7.3\share\doc\hadoop\hadoop-project-dist\hadoop-common\`

Comment: How is this answer diff from existing one? apart from backslash with the forward slash. :)

Answer (score 0):

hdfs-default.xml is present in hadoop-hdfs.jar which the user can't edit. To override these properties of hdfs-default.xml, user is given with hdfs-site.xml(/etc/hadoop/conf)

To view the files in the jar:
jar -tf /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs.jar | grep hdfs-default.xml